# High memory usage Libre Office Writer 7.3.4

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Recently while working on a document in LO Writer I noticed high memory usage after some time (~15 minutes). This kept increasing with every scrolling I did inside the document until all memory was used up and LO Writer crashed. Results were the same on my Laptop as well (both Windows x64 19044).
Starting the application in safe mode seemed to have resolved the issue, although this solution is rather not optimal. Resetting the user data also did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question here, so if anybody finds this in the future it could be helpful to them.
Since the error only happened while scrolling I figured it could have something to do with the graphics.
I resolved the issue by going to

```
Extras -> Options > disable Skia rendering
```

When I executed the graphicstest I also discovered less errors or quirks.